# Asp.Net MVC 4 Partial view very Slow When Publish it on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

my partial view work quickly and well when run it local but when Publish it on server my partial view work very slowly and website is heavy

my partial code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function Son(id)
 {
   this.id_ = id;
   var d = 'div#' + id_;
   var urId = '@Url.Action("Son","Tree")';
   $(d).load(urId , {id:id_}).ajaxSuccess();
   //Son2(id);
 }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function Son2(id)
 {
   this.id_ = id;

   var urId2 = '@Url.Action("DivSon","Tree")';
   $('div.inn_height').load(urId2 , {id:id_}).ajaxSuccess();

 }
</script>
 @{ var father = Model.Where(a => a.Parent_Id == 0).FirstOrDefault();
    var main = Model.Where(a => a.Parent_Id == father.id).ToList();}

 <ul class="list_family">

  @if (main.Count() > 0)
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < main.Count(); i++)
     {
        var item = main.ElementAt(i);
        <li id="@item.id">

          <div>

           <div class="manu">
            @if (item.Wife_Image != null)
            {
              <div class="wife"><img class="img_wife" src="@Url.Content(item.Wife_Image)"></div>
            }

           @if (item.Wife_Image == null && item.IsMarried=="forsale")
           {
             <div class="wife"><img class="img_wife" src="~/Content/img/visa.png" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
           }
           <a onclick="Son('@item.id');Son2('@item.id');">
            <img src="@Url.Content(item.Image)">
           </a>
          </div>
           <i><strong>@item.Name</strong></i>

        </div>
     </li>
  }
 }
</ul>
```

c#

```
    family2016Entities db = new family2016Entities();
    [OutputCache(Duration = 10, Location =   System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Trees.OrderByDescending(a => a.id));
    }
    [OutputCache(Duration = 10, Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient)]
    public ActionResult Son(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.Grand = id;

        var child = db.SELECTTreeSonrecords(id).ToList();

         return PartialView("Son", child);         
    }

    [OutputCache(Duration = 10, Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient)]
    public ActionResult DivSon(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.Grand2 = id;

        var details = db.SELECTTreerecords(id).FirstOrDefault();

        return PartialView("DivSon", details);
    }
```

what can i do to make my partial view work quickly when publish it 
and What's the alternative for partial view to work well

Comment: There looks like there is a recursive call in there to Son2 that would appear to be executing endlessly (there is no condition to escape the calling of Son2 at the end of the function with the same parameter as the current call)

Comment: sorry , It was modified @MikeS

Comment: can you include the calling code? Does the Son function get called for each value in an array or something for example? Is it possible that on the server it is running more frequently then locally?

Comment: include it :) @MikeS

Comment: And is main.Count() a larger number on the server then locally? Is the slowness in the rendering of the partial view or is it slower once it is rendered in the browser?

Comment: the same number on server and local , the slowness in the rendering of the partial view

Comment: If it's in the rendering, then don't look at the javascript, look at the server side code. I assume there is a controller behind the scenes, check in there to see what could be slowing it down. Database connections, queries, indices in the database? If you are using a different data source on the server then locally, you could try hooking your local service up to the server's data source.

Comment: Include code c# @MikeS

Comment: And the code for the 'son' partial view? Is that what you have at the top? Is it a recursive view?

Comment: it was modified  @MikeS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134104/discussion-between-asmaa-mohamed-and-mikes).